# How to get Azure Notification Hub Registered Device list

Tags: .net, azure, azure-notificationhub

I am using below code but still getting hanging issue on line:-

```
 var allRegistrations = await hub.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(0);
```

**My Code is :-**

```
NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("Endpoint=XXXXXX.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXX", "My hub name", true);

var allRegistrations = await hub.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(0);
```

Please provide better solution..

Thanks

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Issue with getting list of registered device on azure

Comment: Errors, etc, not asking to repeat the question. Any reason you know of? What you have provided is not enough to go on.

Comment: I can get the registrations with you mentioned code. If you meet some issue, you could descript the issue details. What version of SDK you are using? How do you configurate you notification hub? What the detail error message is?

Comment: How to get list of all device to which notification is send? i mean how to confirm notification is send ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I test it with Universal Windows Platform apps, it works correclty on my side.You could  follow the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification) to get start. I use the notification SDK [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/1.0.9)

**Test result:**

I check the active device registrered from azure portal.

[image]

**Debug from code:**

[image]